# Typescript | Vue3 - How a specific route param can return a array of strings?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

Consider this build error:

```
src/views/IndividualProgramView.vue:18:63 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

18 const ProgramForm = () => programStore.renderProgramExercises(route.params.program);
```

I'm trying to find the param in this route: `/program/1` using `route.params.program`.

How can this ever return `string[]` as a type?

I am then passing this value to a function which is expecting a string:

```
renderProgramExercises(id: string): VNode {
```

How can I fix this build error.

I did the following which works but I feel that is it wrong:

```
renderProgramExercises(id: string | string[]): VNode {
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A route parameter can only be an array when the route is configured with a [repeatable parameter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#repeatable-params):

```js
const router = createRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      // repeatable (0 or more)        param is `string | string[]` (empty string if param absent)
      path: '/programs/:program(\\d+)*', 

      // OR:
      // repeatable (1 or more)        param is `string[]`
      path: '/programs/:program(\\d+)+',

      // OR:
      // non-repeatable (1)              param is `string`
      path: '/programs/:program(\\d+)',
      ⋮
    }
  ]
})
```

For a `*`-repeatable param, its type is either `string` if the param is absent from the URL, or `string[]` otherwise, so get the param value based on its type:

```js
const program = Array.isArray(route.params.program)
                  ? route.params.program[0]
                  : route.params.program;

programStore.renderProgramExercises(program);
```

For a `+`-repeatable param, assume it's **always a `string[]`**, and pass the first array element:

```js
programStore.renderProgramExercises(route.params.program[0]);
```

For a non-repeatable param, assume it's **always a `string`**, and use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (`as` keyword followed by the desired type):

```js
programStore.renderProgramExercises(route.params.program as string);
```

Comment: ideally, for a non-repeatable param (e.g. `:id`), I'd like to see a solution without casting `string[]` to `string`... solving it correctly somehow when defining the routes would be the preferable approach (from TypeScript perspective) instead of a simple `as string` whenever we consume `route.params.id as string` =/ Vuejs is new to me, so I don't have a solution for it just yet...